# matplotlib plot the sum of two lines of different type of arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lines plotted on the graph, but they originate from two different shape of arrays, how can I then plot their sum?

e.g. in the Figure below, I have the data of line1 and line2, how can I have "line 1 + line 2"?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,1,1],label='line 1')
plt.plot([1.5,2.5],[2,2],label='line 2')
plt.plot([1,1.5,2,2.5,3],[1,3,3,3,1],label='line 1+lin 2')
plt.legend(loc=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why does this `plt.plot([1,1.5,2,2.5,3],[1,3,3,3,1],label='line 1+lin 2')` represent the sum of `line1` and `line2`?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I want their magnitutes to be sumed together, for the range from 1.5 to 2.5 especially.

Comment: Are they expected to be of constant y-values for each series as shown?

Comment: You need an algorithm which is smart enough to group all values between integer numbers in same category. Doesn't look trivial to me

Comment: @ReedinationerNot really, my datas are much larger, but misaligned. I just make this as a easy sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to interpolate both datasets on a common basis. Then you can simply add them up.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1, y1 = [1,2,3],[1,1,1]
x2, y2 = [1.5,2.5],[2,2]
# get a sorted list of all x values
x = np.unique(np.concatenate((x1,x2)))
# interpolate y1 and y2 on the combined x values
yi1 = np.interp(x, x1, y1, left=0, right=0)
yi2 = np.interp(x, x2, y2, left=0, right=0)


plt.plot(x1, y1, label="Line 1")
plt.plot(x2, y2, label="Line 2")
plt.plot(x, yi1 + yi2, label="Line 1 + Line 2")

plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image]